# ¿Cómo subir un archivo y renombrarlo en laravel 7?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

tengo un formulario donde inserto datos de nuevos productos, logro insertar la imagen, lo que quiero es que en mi bd solo se guarde el nombre del archivo y la extension ejm: "imagen.jpg" no toda la ruta, este es mi código:

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|image'
        ]);
        $imagenes= $request->file('file')->store('public/imagenes');
        $url = Storage::url($imagenes);

        $productos = new producto();    
        $productos->nombre_producto = $request->nameProd;
        $productos->img1_producto = $url;            
      
        $productos->save();    
        return redirect()->route('productos.index')->with('insertar', 'ok');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se puede hacer, una vez lo hice.
Modifica tu codigo asi:

```
             $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|image'
            ]);

            //Obtener el nombre de la imagen completo con su extension
            $nombre_imagen_con_extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();

            // Obtener solo el nombre de la imagen, sin la extension
            $nombre_imagen = pathinfo($nombre_imagen_con_extension,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            
            //Obtener solo la extension de la imagen
            $extension_imagen = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();

            /**
             * Aqui especificas el nombre de la imagen que quieres guardarlo asi: imagen.jpg
             * pero si por casualidad se llega a subir dos imagenes con el mismo nombre y
             * la misma extension habria un error o se reemplazaria la imagen anterior,
             * es por eso que deberias concatenar el nombre de las imagenes con algun
             * numero o texto aleatorio asi: imagen_4374384738.jpg
             */

            $nombre_a_guardar = $nombre_imagen.'.'.$extension_imagen;
            // $nombre_a_guardar = $nombre_imagen.'_'.time().'.'.$extension_imagen; //por si lo quieres hacer asi

            // Subir la imagen
         $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/imagenes',$nombre_a_guardar);

        $productos = new producto();    
        $productos->nombre_producto = $request->nameProd;
        $productos->img1_producto = $nombre_a_guardar;            
      
        $productos->save();    
        return redirect()->route('productos.index')->with('insertar', 'ok');
```

Algo importante a notar es que las imagenes se guardan en el directorio storage/public/imagenes, cuando trate de mostrar las imagenes en mi formulario me presento un error, no las podia cargar desde ese directorio. asi que lo que hice fue una referencia a las imagenes en mi directorio pulic, asi : `php artisan storage:link`  de esa forma las imagenes tambien se guardan en mi directorio public/storage/imagenes  y asi los pude mostrar en html.